# How can you assign an integer value to a list of values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, retention

My set of results looks something like this:

```
date      | count
----------+------
12/1/17   | 13
12/2/17   | 15
12/3/17   | 2
```

I would like to add a column to assign a value to the date value, based on it's position in the results, like this:

```
date      | count  | day
----------+--------+------
12/1/17   | 13     | 1
12/2/17   | 15     | 2
12/3/17   | 2      | 3
```

How can this be done?

If it helps, this is my query:

```
select
    a.date
    count(a.user_id)
from
    tableOne a,
    tableTwo b
where
    a.user_id = b.user_id
group by
    a.date
order by
    a.date asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
    a.date,
    count(a.user_id) Counts,
    row_number() over (order by CASE WHEN counts=0 THEN '01/01/01' ELSE a.date END) as days
from
    tableOne a,
    tableTwo b
where
    a.user_id = b.user_id
group by
    a.date
order by
    a.date asc;
```

**Result:**

```
date        counts  days
2017-12-04  0       1
2017-12-01  13      2
2017-12-02  15      3
2017-12-03  2       4
```

This may helps.

Comment: What about when the count is zero? Is there any way to make a value show up?

Comment: @user2928789 If the count is zero, you want that row at the top of the list, right?